# What are the keyboard-shortcuts for Matchbox window manager?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, matchbox

There doesn't seem to be anything related in the `man` pages for the matchbox executables. Googling & SO'ing has not led to me to anything, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from digging through the [XML file in Matchbox's Git repo](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/matchbox-history/plain/matchbox-documentation/manual/matchbox-manual.xml):

The window manager has redefinable shortcut keys which can be used to perform window operations or launch applications. The location of the config file is `PREFIX/share/matchbox/kbdconfig`, this can be overridden by the user having a `~/.matchbox/kdbconfig` file.

The config file is made up of one definition per line each in the format

`<keys definition>=<action>`

'Keys Definition' consists of an optional series of modifier keys in angle brackets followed by the actual key symbol. Action can be one of next, prev, close, taskmenu, hidetitle, fullscreen and desktop for various window operations.

The action can be prefixed with special characters to launch applications.

Prefixes are:

`!`   Launch application with just a standard fork-exec.
`!!`  Launch application with 'startup-notification' - provides feedback of application startup cycle. **Application must support startup notification ( eg use gtk 2.2 toolkit )

`!$` Launch or raise preexisting application, keeping just a single instance running.

For example:

`<ctrl><alt>p=prev`

Binds the combination of alt, ctrl and p to show the previous window.

`<ctrl>x=!xterm`

Binds the combination of `c-x` to launch an xterm.

**See the installed kbdconfig file for more examples.